# Live AngularJS content in Google Maps infowindow

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

I'm trying to populate a Google Maps infoWindow with AngularJS including ng-include, ng-show and ng-click. I want the user to be able to click any where on the map and get an info window showing all the items found there and have actions which they can perform on those items. 
The first time the user clicks on the map the content of the infoWindow is set and then compiled after a short delay allowing Google Maps to create the infoWindow.

```
infoWindow.setContent(contentString);               
infoWindow.open(me.map,target);         
setTimeout(function(){
        $compile($('#infoWindow'))($scope);
        $scope.$digest();
}, 200);
```

This window works fine, the ng-show directives within that content work because I can affect them using other parts of the page. If the second click just tries to reuse the window

```
infoWindow.open(me.map,marker);
```

the content has not been changed by me but now is displayed with all the curly braces showing `{{`, to me that means GM has saved the content somewhere and regenerates the infoWindow from its copy when I call `open`.

If I call `compile` and `digest` again all the infoWindow looks correct, but behind the scene it has called the `ng-show` directive twice as many times as with the first window (although both with the same list of items found at the new click location). On the third click it calls it three times more than at first and so on. I've put a tracker in when it builds the content string so that each window sends a different number to the function that `ng-show` calls and it appears that there are now three independent infoWindows somewhere on my page and they are all cycling though the `ng-repeat` every time I click and change the items in that list.

Since not-compiling doesn't work, and re-compiling doesn't work, the only thing I have left to do is hunt down and annihilate the ghost infoWindows. But I don't know how.

Comment: Why can't you keep recompiling? so every time a user clicks on a different region, just close the old infoWindow, and open a new infoWindow and compile. And also, check out the docs, I find them very helpful [**here**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#InfoWindow). I personally think that it is not google maps api that's creating and storing a ghost infoWindow somewhere.

Comment: I do keep compiling, and that ends up with multiple ghosts of the info window content. I'm reusing the same infoWindow, but the number of calls to the function I put in `ng-show` shows that every infoWindow that has been opened since the page was reloaded is still there and running in the background somewhere.